# MATLAB: nchoosek of a vector

Tags: performance, matlab, combinations

Let `x = [3:10]`. I want to find `nchoosek(x(i),3)` for each `i`. Is there a function (or a better way) that does this without using a `for` loop?

The function `nchoosek` does accept a vector as its first argument but the output is the different 3 elements from the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [`factorial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/factorial.html) function and compute `nchoosek` manually.  Recall the formula for `nchoosek`:

[image]

As such, we can use `factorial` to help in this computation, which also accepts arrays and matrices of any shape.  Therefore, your code would simply be:

```
y = factorial(x) ./ (factorial(3) .* factorial(x-3));
```

Given `x = 3:10`, we get:

```
y =

     1     4    10    20    35    56    84   120
```

However, if you want to do `nchoosek(x, 3)` for any value of `x >= 3`, you can simply find the closed form expression and avoid having to use `factorial` all together.  To achieve what you desire, use the above expression for `nchoosek` and simply substitute `n` for `x` and `k` for 3:

[image]

As you can see, what you want simplifies to:

[image]

for any value of `x` so long as it's greater than or equal to 3.  Therefore, for each value of `x`, simply compute an element-wise expression like so:

```
y = x.*(x-1).*(x-2) / 6;
```

Given `x = 3:10`, we thus get again:

```
y =

     1     4    10    20    35    56    84   120
```

Answer (score 2):

Exploiting the relationship between factorial and Euler's [`gamma`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html) function:

```
x = 3:10;
k = 3;
result = gamma(x+1)/gamma(k+1)./gamma(x-k+1);
```

Better yet, work with logarithms directly (using [`gammaln`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html)). This will let you compute for large `x` and `k` without overflow. Apply [`round`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) at the end to remove any spurious fractional parts caused by finite numerical precision.

```
result = round(exp(gammaln(x+1)-gammaln(k+1)-gammaln(x-k+1)));
```

Another approach, for `x` of the form `k`,`k+1`, ... (as in your example):

```
result = [1 cumprod(x(2:end)./(x(2:end)-k))];
```